# Missing dll files in my app when using ffmpeg libs (dll)

Tags: dll, ffmpeg, runtime-error, mingw-w64, msys2

I have built ffmpeg v3.2.4 shared libraries (dll) in windows 8.1, core i-7, using mingw-64 and msys2.
The reason was to update my old libraries that were used in my project.
The build was OK.

Also, my application has successfully linked with those dll's.
However, when I am running my app, I got a message `program can't start because libiconv-2.dll is missing in your computer`. I overcome this issue by adding `--disable-iconv` switch in `configure` before running `make` to build the ffmpeg libs from sources.
Then I got the same message with zlib dll missing. Then added `--disable-zlib` switch. 
But then, I got `libbz2-1.dll` is missing when running the app. I don't know how to solve the last one, but, what am I missing here? Why didn't I need all these dll file in the old ffmpeg version ([0.7.17](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=shortlog;h=n0.7.17)) and now I do ([latest ffmpeg](https://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git) (checked out tag n3.2.4)) ??

Thanks for the answers,
Aviv

Comment: You'll probably want to disable all libs mentioned in `EXTERNAL_AUTODETECT_LIBRARY_LIST` in configure.

Comment: ffmpeg just has a dependency on a lot of libraries, required to get its job done.  Resistance is futile, and hoping that some other program's installer puts them in a directory on the PATH is guaranteed to break your program, simply copy the DLLs into the same directory as the .exe

Comment: Is there a simple way to disable usage of these external dependencies? Or should I use one '--disable' switch per each library/dependency?

Comment: It's a little weird that i need to copy dll's that I never did after updating ffmpeg libs version. Also, my project is compiled to linux as well, and I never had to copy those external libraries next to the executable

Comment: it seems to be bzlib that requires libbz2-1.dll, so --disbale-bzlib might solve this, but just doing what Gyan says might be best as usual (--disable-autodetect)